# Two axis rotation collide in css 3d rotation

Tags: html, css, rotation

Please examine that example: https://jsfiddle.net/ndp0w3L1/2/embedded/result/

If you rotate `section.diceswrap` over y-axis to 90deg as the second dice in the example: `transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(90deg) rotateZ(0deg);` the rotation in the rest of the axis is the same, it collides and goes only up and down.

This is in FF and webkit.
Am I missing something because it seems that the rotation is actually implemented as 2D and there's no real 3D and if you flip the plane in right angle the rest of axes collide.

HTML:

```
<div class="dice_container">
  <section id="done" class="diceswrap">
    <div class="dice">
      <section class="dice_plane">
        <div class="face one zindx1">
          <span></span>
        </div>
        <div class="face two">
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
        </div>
        <div class="face three"> <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
        </div>
        <div class="face four"> <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
        </div>
        <div class="face five">
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
        </div>
        <div class="face six">
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body, pre {
  font: normal normal normal 100 % /20px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.dice_container {
  padding: 10 % ;
  text - align: center;
  background - color: #333;
}
.diceswrap {
    width: 178px;
    height: 178px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.dice {
    width: 104px;
    height: 104px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}
.face {
    padding: 12px;
    width: 104px;
    height: 104px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: # e7e7e7;
  border: 1 px solid# ccc;
}
.face span {
  width: 24 px;
  height: 24 px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background - color: #333;
  box-shadow: inset 0 3px # 111,
  inset 0 - 3 px #555;
}
.one span {
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -12px 0 0 -12px;
}
.two span:nth-of-type(1) {
    left: 12px;
}
.two span:nth-of-type(2) {
    top: 68px;
    left: 68px;
}
.three span:nth-of-type(1) {
    left: 12px;
}
.three span:nth-of-type(2) {
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -12px 0 0 -12px;
}
.three span:nth-of-type(3) {
    top: 68px;
    left: 68px;
}
.four span:nth-of-type(1) {
    left: 12px;
}
.four span:nth-of-type(2) {
    left: 68px;
}
.four span:nth-of-type(3) {
    top: 68px;
    left: 12px;
}
.four span:nth-of-type(4) {
    top: 68px;
    left: 68px;
}
.five span:nth-of-type(1) {
    left: 12px;
}
.five span:nth-of-type(2) {
    left: 68px;
}
.five span:nth-of-type(3) {
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -12px 0 0 -12px;
}
.five span:nth-of-type(4) {
    top: 68px;
    left: 12px;
}
.five span:nth-of-type(5) {
    top: 68px;
    left: 68px;
}
.six span:nth-of-type(1) {
    left: 12px;
}
.six span:nth-of-type(2) {
    left: 68px;
}
.six span:nth-of-type(3) {
    top: 50%;
    left: 12px;
    margin: -12px 0 0 0;
}
.six span:nth-of-type(4) {
    top: 50%;
    left: 68px;
    margin: -12px 0 0 0;
}
.six span:nth-of-type(5) {
    top: 68px;
    left: 12px;
}
.six span:nth-of-type(6) {
    top: 68px;
    left: 68px;
}
.dice {
    perspective: 1000px;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: transform 0.5s linear;
}
.dice_plane {
    position: absolute;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: transform 0.4s linear;
    transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.ftwo .dice_plane {
    transform: rotateX(-90deg) rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(0deg) !important;
}
.fthree .dice_plane {
    transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(-90deg) rotateZ(0deg) !important;
}
.ffour .dice_plane {
    transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(90deg) rotateZ(0deg) !important;
}
.ffive .dice_plane {
    transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(90deg) rotateZ(90deg) !important;
}
.fsix .dice_plane {
    transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(0) !important;
}
.one {
    transform: translateZ(52px);
    rotateY(90deg);
}
.six {
    transform: translateZ(-52px);
}
.three {
    transform: translateX(52px) rotateY(90deg);
}
.four {
    transform: translateX(-52px) rotateY(-90deg);
}
.five {
    transform: translateY(52px) rotateX(90deg);
}
.two {
    transform: translateY(-52px) rotateX(-90deg);
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ndp0w3L1/2/

Appreciate your kind help

Answer (score 1):

This is what I found in my research:

Both `rotateX` ,`rotateY` transform properties rotate the object  around the horizontal and vertical axes respectively and the third `rotateZ` gives rotation around third vector.
This vector in `rotateX(0deg) rotateY(90deg) rotateZ(0deg)` case scenario is in the same plane with horizonal X-axis so both  rotation of X,Y collides.

You can give the vector any direction so the problematic

`rotateX(0deg) rotateY(90deg) rotateZ(0deg)`

is equivalent to

`rotateX(0deg) rotateY(90deg) rotate3d(0,0,1, 0deg)`

and `rotate3d(1,0,0, 0deg)` would restore the rotation in 3d in the given example.

So any of the axes can be put in `rotate3d` format